# Add a comment row after a row if condition is met in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I can figure out a way to do it with `iterrows` or `itertuples` but I was looking for a more efficient way (probably with a lambda function).
Code and data for the purpose of this question:

```
import pandas
a = {'a': [1,3,5,7], 'b': [2,4,6,8], 'c': [3,5,7,9]}
b = pandas.DataFrame(a)
b
Out[4]: 
a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  5
2  5  6  7
3  7  8  9
```

If for the sum of the digits in a row: `sum_row % 4 = 0`, the program adds a row below row. The added row is not divided into columns, but rather it consists of a single cell with a comment.
Desired resulting dataframe should look like that:

```
a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  5
2  sum_row % 4 yields no remainder
3  5  6  7
4  7  8  9
5  sum_row % 4 yields no remainder
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Show us sample input, expected output and what have you tried so far ([mre]).

Comment: Please explain your question with an example.

Comment: @buran I added mock data for the purpose of this question. Thanks.

Comment: @MohammadrezaRiahi I added mock data for the purpose of this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is my interpretation: He needs evaluate "mod 4" (% 4) in every row. This is my old school loop into DATAFRAME using iterrows. With this code you can create a new DF into Loop, or create a D column with % 4 result.

```
import pandas as pd

# Loop in DATAFRAME

a = {'a': [1,3,5,7], 'b': [2,4 ,6, 8], 'c': [3, 5,7,9]}
b = pd.DataFrame(a)

# Print Data Frame
# print (b) 
for index, x in b.iterrows():
  # Print Line
  print (x['a'] , x['b'] , x['c'] )
  result = (x['a'] + x['b'] + x['c'] ) % 4
  if result == 0:
    # Print Result
    print ('sum_row % 4 yields no remainder')
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired output as shown is not possible. You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

spam = {'a': [1,3,5,7], 'b': [2,4 ,6, 8], 'c': [3, 5,7,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(spam)
df['remainder'] = (df.sum(axis=1) % 4).astype(bool)
df['comment'] = df.remainder.apply(lambda x: 'remainder' if x else 'no remainder')
print(df)
```

output

```
   a  b  c  remainder      comment
0  1  2  3      True     remainder
1  3  4  5     False  no remainder
2  5  6  7      True     remainder
3  7  8  9     False  no remainder
```

Comment: Thanks @buran. Apparently the task I got was different from what I initially thought. I changed the question accordingly.